# Having a extra optional type, why its required when its being set as a prop?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, volar

so I've recently came across this case, having these 3 interfaces:

```
interface a {
  id: string,
  name: string
}

interface b {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  age: string,
}

interface c {
  id: string,
  name:string,
  color: string
}
```

Assinging these types to a variable:

```
const selectedType: Ref< a | b | c | null> = ref(null);
```

and having a component (lest call it modal):

```
<LW2Modal :title="'modal'" v-model:currentType="selectedType" /></LW2Modal>
```

which its props are:

```
const props = withDefaults(
    defineProps<{
        currentType: a | b | null
    }>(),
    {},
);
```

It's giving an error that I'm missing ("c") obviously, but this modal is only intended to modify a | b, **I'm doing this TO NOT HAVE MULTIPLE VARIABLES WHEN SELECTING ANY TYPE**

is there a way for typescript to accept this?

**Thanks guys** :)

Comment: but this modal is only intended to modify a | b - can you clarify? Is it guaranteed that selectedType is not c?

Comment: Yeah, Im making sure of it, its only run in really specific scenarios

Comment: You need to narrow down selectedType type at some point, the most simple is `selectedType as a | b` but it's preferable to do this in script part rather than template. If there's a condition somewhere that's responsible for not letting it be c then this would be the right place for TS typeguard. If there's none then this could be a sign that the app is not type safe and doesn't use TS to full extent